# Create Oracle PL/SQL procedure that outputs distinct names inside a loop

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, procedure

I just started with PL/SQL, so, please be kind.
I have a simple problem, I want to extract distinct names from a table.
When I do that, inside the loop, I am going to do on each of those distinct names some other operations.

I am stuck on how to get the unique names inside a loop. What I do is not working because if I have:

```
1 MARY
2 MARY
3 JOHN
```

I am outputting:

```
MARY
MARY
```

Instead of:

```
MARY
JOHN
```

This is my code:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE CREATE_TABLE 
(
NM  OUT VARCHAR2,
tot OUT NUMBER
)
AS

BEGIN
SELECT count(DISTINCT NAME) INTO tot FROM MYTABLE;


FOR r IN 1..tot
LOOP
SELECT NAME INTO NM
FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT NAME,
      ROWNUM rnum
      FROM MYTABLE
      ORDER BY NAME DESC
     ) 
WHERE rnum = r;

dbms_output.put_line (NM);
END LOOP;

END;
```

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT NAME, ROWNUM rnum` is a source of your problems - since rownum is unique for all records, then `DISTINCT` is reduntant. You have got 2 `Mary` from the subquery, first with rownum 1 and second with rownum 2. Why do you use `rownum` here ? I dont understand your intention.

Comment: For each unique name I need to do some operation (join with other tables, etc.). All I need is to have a loop, and inside that loop extract, one at a time, the distinct names. So, in this case, I want MARY and then JOHN, so that I can, for example, join with another table that has other attributes pertaining to JOHN or MARY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use an implicit cursor loop instead, they're very easy to work with.

```
FOR r in (SELECT DISTINCT NAME
  FROM MYTABLE
  ORDER BY NAME DESC)
LOOP
  NM := r.NAME;
  dbms_output.put_line (NM);
END LOOP;
```

Comment: That's much better! Thanks!